# Communicate to a server in a different subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, samba

I have a router `MW301R` Mercusys  that is connected to a `ADSL` modem with the IP `192.168.1.54` in the `WAN`. In this subnet `1.*` I have a `Samba server`
. The problem is that when the `DHCP` server assigns IPS its in the subnet `0.*` Subnet not in the `1.*` I know that `WAN` subnet cannot be the same that `LAN`, but what can I do, to solve this problem? How can I connect to a server in a different subnet ?

Edit
There's a building with a network `192.168.1.x` so I'm trying to use this connection and there is a router in the other building, this router is connected through an Ethernet cable to receive internet from `192.168.1.x` network, but when im trying to connect to the router the `DHCP` server assigns me a `192.168.0.*` subnet so I can't connect to a server in the other subnet :( English is not my first language.

Comment: Do you mean that 192.168.1.x (with the Samba server) is on the Mercusys router's WAN side and 192.168.0.x is on the LAN side, or the other way around? And are you actually _having_ problems making the connection, or is this a hypothetical question? (I'm asking because connections from LAN side to WAN side are kinda supposed to work by default... that's how you're accessing the Internet right now.)

Comment: There's a building with a network 192.168.1.x so I'm trying to use this connection and there is a router in the other building, this router is connected through an Ethernet cable to receive internet from 192.168.1.x network, but when im trying to connect to the router the DHCP server assigns me a 192.168.0.* subnet so I can't connect to a server in the other subnet :( English is not my first language.

Comment: Do you know for sure that you're unable to connect simply because it's in a different subnet, and not for some other reason? Could it be that the Samba server was configured to disallow these connections?

Comment: It sounds like you may inadvertently be doing double-NAT. If the modem/router is 192.168.1.54 (and that is how you see it from the LAN, that is the LAN side - and any router you add using anything from the 192.168.1.x subnet to create your network is another NAT. You can either set up routes on the routers so both sides know how to traverse that properly, or you can remove your NAT/DHCP (eg, disable the router) on your network so that everything gets assigned from the 192.168.1.x subnet.